# How many arithmetic instructions are too many?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fragment-shader, cg

Currently I am trying to make some shader textures for a game and I am using perlin noise to do so, each time I get a noise value, it adds about 730 instructions to the shader, how many instructions should i aim for?

What video cards would support 10,000+ instructions? Is this a issue at all?
Using NumMathInstructionSlots to change the default may cause compatibility issues?

Comment: After i did a couple more tests i found out that i am under a hardcap of 1024

Comment: Your question is more directly related to Unity's [shader profiles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-ShaderPrograms.html) which offer differing #s of operations based on the `target` profile.  It's certainly possible your hardware is the limit but if you're testing on Windows I suspect you have more power to utilize.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving as much as you can to the vertex shader -- you might want to look through the old NVIDAI shader library for some samples http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/webpages/shader_library.html -- look at "vbomb" as an example.